# Trigger MouseMove Event for Specific Number of Time

Tags: c#, winforms, menu

I have a custom **CustomToolStripMenuItem** which is **derived from ToolStripMenuItem Class**. In that custom class '**CustomToolStripMenuItem**', I **override OnPaint(), OnMouseMove() and OnMouseDown() Events**. 
Here, *I want to add a rectangle to show on each sub menu to delete that menu item from customized tool strip menu items. When user move mouse to rectangle area, it will change back color which shows that user want to delete that item.* I add these menus by reading an xml file.

*The main problem here is that, when I move the mouse from one menu item to other quickly, previous item also shown as selected*.  **How can I ensure that when mouse move to other menu item, previous selection should erase.**

What I guess, **I need to repeat that mouse move event for specific times** (total items in xml file), but **How can I do this with events of mouse** ???
Any Help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [MouseLeave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave.aspx) event with current events, if fast mouse move bypasses your current MouseMove event!

Comment: Well, elegant idea. But, how can I pass PaintEventArgs to LeaveEvent. Beacause, I need to refill the rectangle to show disable that item. But, in LeaveEvent we have no access to PaintEventArgs. Any trick to get PaintEventArgs in LeaveEvent ?

Comment: Yes! define a PaintEventArgs pea; and assign e to pea in paint event handler, then you can use pea in LeaveEvent. If you just need Graphics from PaintEventArgs, then you can skip this solution and use CreateGraphics method of control when needed :)